# Adding an Entry to a NSDictionary doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios

I've got the following question. I want to add 4 entries to an Dictionary, this is xml driven. So there are 4 entries in the xml file. I use the following code in the xml parser to add all the entries :

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{ 
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Placemark"]) {
        NSString *batsen = [placemarkData objectForKey:@"name"];
        [Placemarks setObject:placemarkData forKey:batsen];
        NSLog(@"adding story: %@", batsen);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it looks like he overwrites the entries in Placemarks. If I read out the log file I only see the last entry. That's strange because the log (adding story) does show 4 log messages.

I use the following code to read out the Placemark dictionary:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [appDelegate.Placemarks keyEnumerator];
id key;

while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {

    /* code that uses the returned key */
    NSString *theElement = key;
    NSLog(@"Element: %@", theElement);
}
```

Anyone an suggestion? Thnx in advance

Comment: How and when are you initialising Placemarks. I would expect it to be a (readwrite,retain) property. Seems like you might be initialising each time.  btw normal convention is lower-case for first letter of ivars & properties as in appDelegate.placemarks . Using Placemarks would imply that its a class declaration

Answer (score 2):

When you set a value to an existing key of a NSMutableDictionary the previous value is released :

```
If aKey already exists in the dictionary, 
the dictionary’s previous value object for that key is sent a release message 
and anObject takes its place.
```

[c.f on NSMutableDictionary in Apple API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In your case, your dictionary key should map to an array (NSMutableArray) so you can store a key which refers to 4 xml elements.

Comment: Thnx, for your answer! However, the key is everytime different and not existing. The variable "batsen" is different everytime the code is executed (I can see this in the log)

Answer (score 0):

**NSMutableDictionary** is needed to add entries to a dictionary. This code snippet uses a DRY method to simplify making a new, expanded immutable **NSDictionary**:

```
// Make an immutable dictionary by combining 2 dictionaries (new entries are added, old entries are updated)
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)original WithAddedEntries:(NSDictionary *)entriesToAdd
{
    NSMutableDictionary *final = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:original];
    [final addEntriesFromDictionary:entriesToAdd];
    // Done
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:final];
}
```